# unrecognied selector ... error IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

please can s.o help me to resolve this problem :

> [UITabBarController setTexteAAfficher:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7599e30

this is my code :

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"detailSegue"])
    {

        NSInteger selectedIndex = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] row];
        Infos *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
       dvc.texteAAfficher= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [maListe objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]];
     }
}    `
```

> i'm trying to pass informations from a tableView to a Tab Bar View

Comment: That error description isn't even relevant to the code you have posted. Furthermore, you **will** be format your post before anybody answers.

Comment: can u post the method

Comment: there is no method called setTexteAAfficher but i resolved the problem by importing the class in the right file

Answer (score 3):

As per your error from the code

```
[UITabBarController setTexteAAfficher:]
```

There is no such method in `UITabBarController`.

Have you made a category on UITabBarController with a method named: `setTexteAAfficher` (in some mixed language with English)?

If yes you have missed to `#import` the category file.

Comment: Welcome :) And what was the error please tell.